# String Pattern to match "x by y"

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I'm trying to create a string pattern which will match either (with quotes included):

- "x by y"
- x by y
- 'x by y'

I've tried to use the following pattern: `"\"" ~~ ___ ~~ "by" ~~ ___ ~~ "\""` which only matches something with `"` and tried to find an "or" symbol similar to regex `|` but to no avail.

**Question:** What symbols / tools can I use to develop a pattern which matches the above cases?

**Question:** What is the "correct" translation from a regex approach to a Mathematica approach? Are they the same?

Comment: For string patterns there is also `|` (`Alternatives`) as can be seen  [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html) where regex - which can also be used directly - are compared with string patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
quotePattern = { "\"" , "'", "" };
stringPattern = quotePattern ~~ __ ~~ "by" ~~ __ ~~ quotePattern;

StringMatchQ[ #, stringPattern ] & /@ { "x by y", "\"x by y\"", "'x by y'" }
```

> { True, True, True }

**Edit**

Be careful what you wish for ... as they say:  The OP wants to extract "*title* by *author*" from a list of strings I assume. For example:

```
string = "Some surrounding text. \"The Machine That Changed the World\" by Womack, Jones, and Roos. And it fails.";
```

Now the above pattern will of course not work. We have to be more precise:

```
quotePatternMod = { "\"", "'" };
StringCases[ string,
    Shortest[a : quotePatternMod ~~ b : __ ~~ c : "by" ~~ d : ___ ~~ "."] :> a ~~ b ~~ c ~~ d
]
```

> {"\"The Machine That Changed the World\" by Womack, Jones, and Roos"}

Comment: I have a follow up question, if you don't mind. I'm trying to use `StringCases` using the pattern you provided to this string `"Some surrounding text. \"The Machine That Changed the World\" by \
Womack, Jones, and Roos. And it fails."` And it fails to extract the matching string. Am I using something wrong?

Comment: @JeelShah You will have to add `Shortest` to the pattern otherwise the whole string will match.

Comment: @Jeel What should be the string that is extracted in the case you gave? If it were "booktitle by authors" then you might want to go for a period at the end.

Comment: It should be `"The Machine That Changed the World" by Womack, Jones, and Roos.` and only that. I changed the pattern to: `Shortest[quotePattern ~~ __ ~~ quotePattern ~~ "by" ~~ ___ ~~ "."]` which removes the "And it fails." however, it keeps the preceding string. Is there a way to force that only something which fits that pattern completely is selected? I tried putting "Some surrounding text." in quotes and that was also extracted. `StringCases["\"Some surrounding text.\" \"The Machine That Changed \
the World\" by Womack, Jones, and Roos [0]. And it fails.", \
stringPattern]`

Comment: This works brilliantly! thank you! Is it correct for me to say that we by doing `a: ...` we are assigning `a, b, c, d` to values such as `"` or `1 or more character` and then creating a `StringExpression` using `a ~~ b ~~ c ~~ d`? Why is it that quotePatternMod needs to only be mentioned once? Thanks again!

Comment: @Jeel `name : pattern` simply names a  pattern you can find it under `Pattern` in the documentation.